# Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadGridView get column FormatString from Resource

Tags: c#, resources, telerik, radgridview

i use Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadGridView in visual studio 2010 c# project with .net 4
but i have a problem 
when i open form in designer mode without any change

form.designer.cs code changed like below for all columns in radgrideview

```
gridViewDecimalColumn1.FormatString = global::Projectname.Resource.name;
```